# Socket GetSocketOption()/SetSocketOption with SendLowWater C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am having trouble in using the GetSocketOption() and SetSocketOption() method with SendLowWater in the socket class.

I tried using

```
byte[] values = new byte[100];
sock.GetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket, System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.SendLowWater, values);
```

I get the following exception at the function call: **An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call**

Does anyone know how to use GetSocketOption/SetSocketOption with SendLowWater?

Thank you,
kab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

`SocketOptionName.SendLowWater` corresponds to `SO_SNDLOWAT` (4099), which the [MSDN documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms740532) as not supported:

> A socket option from BSD UNIX included for backward compatibility.
>   This option sets the minimum number of bytes to process for socket
>   output operations.
>
> This option is not supported by the Windows TCP/IP provider. If this
>   option is used on Windows Vista and later, the getsockopt and
>   setsockopt functions fail with `WSAEINVAL`. On earlier versions of
>   Windows, these functions fail with `WSAENOPROTOOPT`.

The `Socket` class is a low-level wrapper around the Winsock functions, so if something fails, you can generally find more detailed information by figuring out what native call your operation corresponds to (in this case `setsockopt`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the error message is pretty self-explanatory: the "send low water" option is not supported on Windows.

Fortunately, you don't really need this option. It's used to control the behavior of the Winsock `select()` function, exposed in .NET as `Socket.Select()`, which is not needed nor desired for effective use of the .NET `Socket` class. Instead, you should use one of the asynchronous methods for using `Socket`.

My personal preference now that C# has the `async`/`await` feature is to wrap the `Socket` in a `NetworkStream` and use the `Stream.ReadAsync()` and `Stream.WriteAsync()` methods. Like the other asynchronous methods, these will use IOCP to handle the asynchronous behavior (the most efficient I/O model in Windows), but in a way that is much more convenient than the other two `Socket`-based asynchronous methods.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation as well. Too bad I can only give the right answer to one post.

Comment: That's okay. It's understood only one answer will be accepted, and that which one will be is at the sole discretion of the questioner. Just make sure you've accepted the answer that _you_ feel best addresses your question, and all's good. :)